# How to open videos which has .mpg format, in python

Tags: python, opencv, video, tracking

I am doing object tracking on my videos which are in .mpg format what i am doing is i am using OpenCV to track the objects but i am facing some while opening it in my code i have attached my code.

```
import cv2
import sys

(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    # Set up tracker.
    # Instead of MIL, you can also use

    tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']
    tracker_type = tracker_types[1]
    print(tracker_type)



    if tracker_type == 'MIL':
            tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()


    # Read video
    video = cv2.VideoCapture("Stroll.mpg")

    # Exit if video not opened.
    if not video.isOpened():
        print ("Could not open video")
        sys.exit()

    # Read first frame.
    ok, frame = video.read()
    if not ok:
        print ('Cannot read video file')
        sys.exit()

    # Define an initial bounding box
    bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)

    # Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box
    bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)

    # Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box
    ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)

    while True:
        # Read a new frame
        ok, frame = video.read()
        if not ok:
            break

        # Start timer
        timer = cv2.getTickCount()

        # Update tracker
        ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

        # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)
        fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer)

        # Draw bounding box
        if ok:
            # Tracking success
            p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
            p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)
        else :
            # Tracking failure
            cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)

        # Display tracker type on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2)

        # Display FPS on frame
        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2)

        # Display result
        cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

        # Exit if ESC pressed
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
        if k == 27 : break
```

but the error i am facing here is:-

```
Could not open video
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp
(116) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio
\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find
starting number (in the name of file): Stroll.mpg in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

I am using python 3.6.8
OpenCV version 4.1.2

Answer (score 1):

POSSIBLY WRONG PATH
Check if Stroll.mpg is in right there in your working directory. If yes try with an .mp4 video. Most probably the path is wrong or file name Is misspelled.
Refer: https://answers.opencv.org/question/1965/cv2videocapture-cannot-read-from-file/

Comment: thank you for your response, yes the path was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your opencv is compiled *with ffmpeg* which provides all those media-decoders (probably missing without).

[Someone with a similar problem](https://answers.opencv.org/question/220468/video-from-ip-camera-cant-find-starting-number-cvicvextractpattern/) due to this.